# Tipfy wtform fields always render as input type="text"

Tags: google-app-engine, tipfy, wtforms

I cant find examples of templates that use tipfy forms (extended wtforms). 
For example, If I want to implement birth date I want the "right" html for the user to enter his date of birth. Lets go with an example:

this is my form

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    name = fields.TextField('Nombre',validators=[REQUIRED])
    email = fields.TextField('Email', validators=[REQUIRED,VALID_EMAIL])
    birth_date = fields.DateTimeField('Fecha Nacimiento',format='%d/%m/%y',validators=[REQUIRED])
    password = fields.PasswordField('Password', validators=[REQUIRED])
    password_confirm = fields.PasswordField('Confirm the password', validators=[REQUIRED])
```

at the template :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ current_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="tipfy-form">
        <ol>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.name, class='medium') }} </li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.email, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.password, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.password_confirm, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.birth_date, class='medium') }}</li>
        </ol>
                        <fieldset class="submit">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{{ _('Register') }}" class="button_auth">
                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```

however, the field for the **form.birth_date** render as html input tag with type="text". Do I have to override the **call** or html method? I want to get render the select tag with options,  so the user selects day/month/year and not by tipping it. **I dont want the user to type a date in a text field**

If I want html5 tags, I must override?

I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment I resolved this using form macros

I had to use the SelectField

```
DAYS = [(x,x) for x in range(1,31)]
MONTHS = [x for x in [('enero',1),('febrero',2),('marzo',3),('abril',4),('mayo',5),('julio',6),('junio',7),('agosto',8),('setiembre',9),('octubre',10),('noviembre',11),('diciembre',12)] ]
YEARS = [(x,x) for x in range(1905,2010)]

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    name = fields.TextField('Nombre',validators=[REQUIRED])
    surnames = fields.TextField('Apellidos',validators=[REQUIRED])
    email = fields.TextField('Email', validators=[REQUIRED,VALID_EMAIL])
    birth_date_day = fields.SelectField('Fecha Nacimiento',format='%d/%m/%y',validators=[REQUIRED])
    password = fields.PasswordField('Password', validators=[REQUIRED])
    password_confirm = fields.PasswordField('Confirm the password', validators=[REQUIRED])
```

this is the new template

```
  <form method="post" action="{{ current_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="tipfy-form">
        <ol>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.name, class='medium') }} </li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.surnames, class='medium') }} </li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.email, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.password, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.password_confirm, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.sex, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.birth_date, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.birth_month, class='medium') }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_field(form.birth_year, class='medium') }}</li>
        </ol>
                        <fieldset class="submit">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{{ _('Register') }}" class="button_auth">
                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```